# Sum data points in the rows from data frame if they meet criteria from another data frame in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, sum, rows

I have two data frames both with 220 obs and 80 variables. The first data frame, `df1`, has only the data points `1`, `2`, and `3`. The second data frame, `df2`, has different numeric values consisting of decimals, such as `0.12`, `-0.03`, `0.01` etc. (supposed to portray market cap weighted stock returns for a given month). PS: The length of the original data set is 80.

For example

```
df1 = data.frame(a = c(2, 2, 1), b = c(3, 2, 3), c = c(1, 1, 2), d = c(3, 3, 1))

  a b c d
1 2 3 1 3
2 2 2 1 3
3 1 3 2 1

df2 = data.frame(a = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.2), b = c(0.3, 0.4, 0.6), c = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5), d = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.6))

    a   b   c   d
1 0.1 0.3 0.2 0.1
2 0.1 0.4 0.3 0.5
3 0.2 0.6 0.5 0.6
```

How can I sum the rows of `df2`and turn into a matrix with 220 obs and 3 variables based on the values in `df1`. Note that `df1` and `df2` have the same column names in the same order. How can I create a third data frame `df3` based on the indicator variables from `df1` by summing the rows of `df2`? I want to sum the rows of `df2` based on the values in `df1` to create `df3`:

```
df3 =
   X1  X2  X3
1 0.2 0.1 0.4
2 0.3 0.5 0.5
3 0.8 0.5 0.6
```

Let's first look at `(X1,1)`. Row `1` in `df1` only contain one data point with value `1`, which is `(c,1)`. Thus, we sum row `1` of `df2` to get `0.2`. Now look at `(X1,3)` (last value of column `X1`). Observe row `3` in `df1` to find two data points with value `1`. In `df2` those two values are `0.2` `(a,3)` and `0.6` `(d,3)`, and sum the values to get `0.8`.

Here is the explanation of how `df3` looks like:

```
calculation = data.frame("1" = c("0+0+0.2+0", "0+0+0.3+0", "0.2+0+0+0.6"), "2" = c("0.1+0+0+0", "0.1+0.4+0+0", "0+0+0.5+0"), "3" = c("0+0.3+0+0.1", "0+0+0+0.5", "0+0.6+0+0"))

                 X1                X2                X3
1   0 + 0 + 0.2 + 0   0.1 + 0 + 0 + 0 0 + 0.3 + 0 + 0.1
2   0 + 0 + 0.3 + 0 0.1 + 0.4 + 0 + 0   0 + 0 + 0 + 0.5
3 0.2 + 0 + 0 + 0.6   0 + 0 + 0.5 + 0   0 + 0.6 + 0 + 0
```

More practical explanation based on stocks. Assume `df1` is a matrix that describes buy, hold, and sell recommendations. `df2` describes the market weighted stock returns. All variables/columns are different stocks. `df3` creates a matrix with three different portfolios. If the stock is "buy", I want to put it in a "buy" portfolio. If the stock is "hold", I want to put it in a "hold" portfolio, etc. This is easily done in Excel with nested `IF`,`AND`,`OR` functions, but I do not know how to do it in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `tapply` by converting the datasets to `matrix`, use grouping variables as the `row` index of the data and the index of 'df1'

```
tapply(as.matrix(df2), list(row(df2), as.matrix(df1)), FUN = sum)
#       1   2   3
#[1,] 0.2 0.1 0.4
#[2,] 0.3 0.5 0.5
#[3,] 0.8 0.5 0.6
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`, bind the datasets after `gather`ing the two in to 'long' data, and then do a group by `sum`

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df1) %>%
    bind_cols(gather(df2)) %>% 
    group_by(key) %>%
    group_by(rn = row_number(), value) %>% 
    summarise(value1 = sum(value1)) %>% 
    spread(value, value1) %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    select(-rn)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#    `1`   `2`   `3`
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1   0.2   0.1   0.4
#2   0.3   0.5   0.5
#3   0.8   0.5   0.6
```

Comment: I tried the `tapply` for my data set, but it gives me 5 arrays instead of 3. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: @Mataunited17  Yes, the only reason is that the lengths are not equal in the original data, while it is the same in the example

Comment: I see. The length of the original data is 80 for both `df1` and `df2`.

Comment: @Mataunited17  I meant the frequency of elements of 'df1' for each row

Comment: Yes. The frequency of the elements of the rows in the original data will differ. However, in the example data, the frequency is 1 or 2 for each row.

Comment: Is it possible to make the `tapply` or `tidyverse` work regardless of the frequency of the elements in each row?

Comment: @Mataunited17  Please update your post with a small example that shows this behavior

Comment: I got it now. I had to remove all of the `0`s and `4`s that made it it into 5 arrays instead of 3. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another base R method that uses `rowsum` to perform group sums and loops through the rows with `mapply`.

```
t(mapply(rowsum, as.data.frame(t(df2)), as.data.frame(t(df1))))
   [,1] [,2] [,3]
V1  0.2  0.1  0.4
V2  0.3  0.5  0.5
V3  0.8  0.5  0.6
```

Note that I am using R 3.4.4. I believe that `as.data.frame` is not necessary with R 3.5.0+, since `t` should return a data.frame when it is fed a data.frame.

Comment: great option.  I was also thinking about the `rowsum`

Comment: This requires a number of transposes, but shouldn't be too bad with moderate size data.

Comment: @lmo this didn't work in my original data set. It just gave me a row vector with multiple character vectors for each data point.

Comment: My guess is that some of your variables are character. The transpose will convert the data.frame to a character matrix. I would suspect that `rowsum` would error on this, but without seeing your original data, it's difficult to diagnose.